# How can I convert this kinda cars.xml file to .csv file?

Tags: xml, csv, opencv

I have a problem with converting .xml file to .csv file where I want to make features classification w.r.t. 3 shape features e.g. rectangular features.
Here I link cars.xml file(https://github.com/shaanhk/New-GithubTest/blob/master/cars.xml) which you can try to convert it to .csv file which I need for my further processing.

Comment: are you trying to create a script for that or are you looking for an existing tool?

Comment: I am looking for a tool which can extract integers into an array,                 eg. 255 1 33                                                                                                                 3 22 138                                                                                                               to [255, 1, 33, 3, 22, 138]